# XGBoost XGBRegressor predict with different dimensions than fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, regression, xgboost

I am using [the xgboost XGBRegressor](https://xgboost.XGBRegressor) to train on a data of 20 input dimensions:

```
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', n_estimators=20)
    model.fit(trainX, trainy, verbose=False)
```

`trainX` is 2000 x 19, and `trainy` is 2000 x 1.

In another word, I am using the 19 dimensions of `trainX` to predict the 20th dimension (the one dimension of `trainy`) as the training.

When I am making a prediction:

```
yhat = model.predict(x_input)
```

`x_input` has to be 19 dimensions.
I am wondering if there is a way to keep using the 19 dimensions to train prediction the 20th dimension. But during the prediction, `x_input` has only 4 dimensions to predict the 20th dimension. It is kinda of a transfer learning to different input dimension.

Does xgboost supports such a feature? I tried just to fill `x_input`'s other dimensions to `None`, but that yields to terrible prediction results.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with regular ML model, why would you need to train and make inference with different data ? Also transfer learning as nothing to do with what you described imo

Comment: It is because during inference, I do not have 19 parameters, but only have 4/19 parameters.

Comment: Don't call them 'dimensions', they're called 'features'. If you'll only have 4 features in the test-set to do inference, then you should only train your model on those 4 features, not all 19. (What *can* you use the extra 15 features for? Exploratory data analysis, investigation, clustering, stratification.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, you're training your model with a dense dataset (19/19 feature values), and are now wondering if you're allowed to make predictions with a sparse dataset (4/19 feature values).

> Does xgboost supports such a feature?

Yes, it is technically possible with XGBoost, because XGBoost will treat the absent 15/19 feature values as missing. It will not be possible with some other ML framework (such as Scikit-Learn) that do not work with sparse input by default.

Alternatively, you can make your XGBoost model explicitly "missing-value-proof" by assembling a pipeline which contains feature imputation step(s).

> I tried just to fill x_input's other dimensions to None, but that yields to terrible prediction results.

You should represent missing values as `float("NaN")` (not as `None`).

Comment: I just filled the inference missing features with `float("NaN")`. It gave me terrible performance. It is way worse than just training with `4/19` features.

Comment: It all depends on your model configuration and dataset. There are no conceptual limitations on the XGBoost side - it will make a prediction even for an empty row vector (`0/19`). If the default handling of missing values ("send in the majority's way") is not good enough for you, then add imputation to your pipeline, so that you'd have 19/19 row vectors entering the `predict(X)` method.

Comment: Do you have a reference on how to impute the missing values for XGBoost? Thanks

Comment: You appear to be using XGBoost via Scikit-Learn API already. Simply create a full-blown SkLearn pipeline, where the first step is `sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer`.

Comment: The performance has been bad with the imputer. I found a better accuracy if I fill the missing features with the features of a previous data point.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to train a model with 19 features, but then feed it only 1 feature to make a prediction.

That's not going to be possible. When you train a model, you are assuming that your data points are drawn from a probability distribution `P(X,Y)`, where Y is your label and X is your features. If you try to change the dimensionality of X, it'll no longer belong to that distribution (at least intuitively, I am not a mathematician so, I cannot come up with a proof for this).

For instance, let's assume your data lies on a 3D cube. That means that you need three coordinate axes to represent a point on it. You cannot place a point using 2 dimensions without assuming the value of the remaining dimension.

You can assume the values of the features you try to drop, but they may not represent the data you originally trained on.